# como instalar oracle 11g r2 expres y sql developer en ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, oracle-11g

tengo 2 archivos.zip y desde la consola intento ejecuatar un archivo que viene dentro de uno de los zip que se llama "RunIntaller" pero sale un error:

Se ha especificado una ruta de acceso de origen no válida '../stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.5.0.17.0/1/DataFiles' para la descompresión. Fallo del comando de descompresión. Compruebe oraparam.ini y especifique una ruta de acceso de origen válida.
: No existe el archivo o el directorio

Answer (score 0):

instalacion oracle 11g:

```
unzip p13390677_112040_LINUX_1of7.zip
unzip p13390677_112040_LINUX_2of7.zip

yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall
mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
chown -R oracle:oinstall /u01
chmod -R 775 /u01
```

debes conectarte al usuario oracle con y en el bash profile setter las variables:

```
su - oracle
vi .bash_profile

# Oracle Settings
TMP=/tmp; export TMP
TMPDIR=$TMP; export TMPDIR

ORACLE_HOSTNAME=ol6-112.localdomain; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_UNQNAME=DB11G; export ORACLE_UNQNAME
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/db_1; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=DB11G; export ORACLE_SID

PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib; export CLASSPATH
```

como user root:

```
SELINUX=permissive
setenforce 0
getenforce # para validar tiene que decir permissive
xhost +
DISPLAY=:0.0; export DISPLAY
su - oracle
DISPLAY=:0.0; export DISPLAY
cd oracle_software
```

luego debes entrar a la carpeta y darle al

```
./runInstaller
```

en caso de error setter la variable de systemas en el archivo `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
oracle              soft    nproc   16384
oracle              hard    nproc   16384
oracle              soft    nofile  4096
oracle              hard    nofile  65536
oracle              soft    stack   10240
```

problemas con el jdk reinstall:
[download jdk](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
fuente:
[install oracle linux](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-db-11gr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-6)